# how to set mr-0 in bootstrap 4 when position absolute

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, margin

For a toast i use in bootstrap, i want to use the class`mr-0` to push the toast to the right side.
But this does not work:

```
<div class="toast hide position-absolute mr-0"  data-autohide="false">
    <div class="toast-header">
         <strong class="mr-auto text-primary">Share Link</strong>         
         <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="toast-body">
    <?php echo $share_link; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

When i use this: `style="right: 0px;"` it works:

```
<div class="toast hide position-absolute" style="right: 0px;" data-autohide="false">
...
```

Can someone tell me why `mr-0` does not work in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use position `relative` to use margin. 
`margin-bottom`, `margin-left`,`margin-right` won't work in absolute positioning ,

Answer (score 1):

`mr-0` is a `margin-right: 0px` and it has no direct impact to `position: absolute`. You can read more about position absolute on [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).